# How to avoid migrating to AndroidX in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, google-api

As Google APIs for Android introduced breaking changes as [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019) I found my self un able to compile my react native android app, there are two things I need to know about:

How to *avoid* migrating to AndroidX and compile my project as I did before?

For example, when I have this error:

```
node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/ReactNativeFirebaseAppRegistrar.java:20: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Keep;
```

how would include that missing package into build.gradle of that module?

I tried:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
  }
```

but it did not help..

Comment: 1) your project randomly broke? Seems unrelated 2) Moving forward, you cannot avoid this migration. Although it does not look like you need to do this yourself. [RN supports androidx from v0.60.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23112#issuecomment-480425712), it's already available in the RC release

Comment: v0.60.0 is still RC, our project stopped compiling.. its not clear what has changed..

Comment: *v0.60.0 is still RC* - yes.. I just said that. How is androidx related to your project not compiling, given that you haven't changed anything?

Comment: When I link some dependency the problem occurs, but I did not update that dependency

Comment: v0.60.0 may be released after months as https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1588#issuecomment-503481594

Comment: @simo can you mention the errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable or avoid androidX with the following step

go to your android/gradle.properties file and paste or update the following

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```

Although it does not update libraries we import or install, So all the libraries should be in AndroidX support otherwise project will not compile with this change I'm also having the same issue in my case project is fine but the problem is with the library called mapbox which have not support androidx I post the issue [here](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/163) you can check issue and comments.